# How do I change css class of html paragraph with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So the way I want to do the toggling of light and dark themes is that every thing that changes will have an other class in css that it will change to.

Like this:

css:

```
.p-fooldal
{
    color:black;
}

.p-fooldal-light-mode
{
    color:white;
}
```

html:

```
<p class="p-fooldal"> asd asd </p>
```

JS is where I need help. I have done the some with the body, but I cant do the same, because I want different style for different paragraphs, **what other way can I refer to** a paragraph.

```
var body = document.body;

function toggleDark()
{
    body.classList.toggle("body-light-mode");
}
```

I have tried bruteforcing myself whit this:

```
const pfooldal = document.classList.pfooldal;

function toggleDark()
{
    pfooldal.classList.toggle("p-fooldal-light-mode")
}
```

I know its awful but it has to be something like that.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. If you want to toggle between dark and light mode, use one class and apply that to `body`. Everything else should be handled using CSS:  `body.light-mode p {}`.

Comment: I think you should reconsider how you are applying the modes, as InSync referred to. Here's a helpful resource: [A Complete Guide to Dark Mode on the Web](https://css-tricks.com/a-complete-guide-to-dark-mode-on-the-web/#aa-using-a-body-class)

Comment: As others have said, use just a class on the body and include that in the selectors. However, about the actual question itself: if you have an always-applied class and a mode class, select by the main class and then force-toggle the mode class. If you are switching between two classes, select elements by the class that should be currently present based on the mode, remove it, and apply the other class.

Comment: `document.classList.pfooldal` is undefined, perhaps you're looking for a `for` loop with `document.getElementsByClassName('pfooldal')[i]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than changing the classes of every element, only toggle the `body-dark-mode` class on `document.body`. Then using CSS, define styles for descendants of `.body-dark-mode`. This way, whenever `document.body` gets the class, every element that has a style defined will also be selected as its child and the alternative CSS will be applied. Like this:

```js
const toggleTheme = document.getElementById('toggleTheme');
toggleTheme.addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.body.classList.toggle("body-dark-mode");
});
```

```css
/* Global dark mode CSS */
.body-dark-mode {
  background: black;
}

/* Default style */
.p-fooldal {
    color: green;
}
/* Alternative dark mode CSS */
.body-dark-mode .p-fooldal {
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<p class="p-fooldal"> asd asd </p>
<button id="toggleTheme">Toggle theme</button>
```

Comment: Thank you! That was very helpful! Can you help me with the js part? Because I didnt use a button, instead I used a checkbox

Comment: @BenjaminKovács I'm not sure what you mean. If you also need to style a checkbox for dark-mode, then you don't need to add any more JS. Just add the dark-mode styles to your CSS in a block for `.body-dark-mode .checkbox-class`, where `checkbox-class` is the class given to the checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

Personally when I implement dark/light modes for websites, I like to create a main.css file that has all the global styles that will apply to both modes. Then create a dark.css and a light.css for your changing colors.

So, for example:

main.css:

```
/* general styles here */
```

dark.css:

```
.p-fooldal {
   color:black;
 }
```

light.css:

```
 .p-fooldal {
   color:white;
 }
```

In your html, you will declare your main.css file first and then whichever light mode you want to be the default. Be sure to include file paths if they aren't all in the same folder.

index.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" id="lightMode" href="dark.css" type="text/css">
```

By declaring your light mode CSS file with an id, you can change it with javascript. Put the following line in your javascript file. You can nest it in a function called by a button or Event Listener and then have it toggle between light.css and dark.css
script.js:

```
document.getElementById('lightMode').setAttribute('href', 'light.css');
```

By doing it this way instead of defining different classes for different elements, you can affect all of your elements with one function call. I know this isn't quite the solution you were looking for, but unless you absolutely need it to be in the format you described, I'd reconsider.

Comment: This does of course require the second file to load before the switch can be completed. It's a tradeoff between that or requesting both up front. Usually, though, the cost of requesting both should be minimal.